# Underscore.js - How to sortby a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have the following javascript object:

```
var appointments = [];

appointments.push(
       { id: '101', 
         status: 'accepted',
         appointmentTimes: [ { from: '2016-10-28 12:00', to: '2016-10-28 13:00' } ] },

       { id: '102', 
         status: 'pending', 
         appointmentTimes: [ { from: '2016-10-24 12:00', to: '2016-10-24 13:00' },  
                             { from: '2016-10-24 15:00', to: '2016-10-24 16:00' } ] });
```

I want to sort the array objects using the first item in the `appointmentTimes` array using the `from` property so that each object appears in ascending date order.

So in the above example, object with id 102 would appear first in the list. Note each item in appointmentTimes array is already in ascending order.

I've tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
_.sortBy(appointments, function(appointments) { 
        return appointments.appointmentTimes.from; 
 });
```

Comment: use return appointments.appointmentTimes[0].from;

Comment: @Vanojx1 Thanks, I managed to figure out myself but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix:

```
_.sortBy(appointments, function(appointment) { 
    return appointment.appointmentTimes[0].from; 
});
```